# Data tables in Pentaho User Console dashboard don't show numbers correctly

Tags: pentaho

I'm trying to insert a table in a `Pentaho` User Console dashboard which shows in the first column the name of a company and in the second column how much they have bought in a specified period of time. However, when previsualizing the numbers from the second column they are displayed in the form `null` + number, like `null23456` and then when the table is created `NaN` is displayed instead of the numbers.

Oddly enough, the table is using the correct number (after the null) and even the order is correct when changing it, it just doesn't show up in the dashboard. It fails for both integers and floating point numbers.

The SQL query I'm using to retrieve the data is the following:

> SELECT Nombre AS Empresa, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM F_factura) AS Año, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM F_factura) AS Mes,
>   EXTRACT(DAY FROM F_factura) AS Día, I_monemp AS Importe
>   FROM Facturas, Rsocial
>   WHERE Facturas.rsocial_cod = Rsocial.cod

Import is the number I am trying to display in the second colum.

[Data correctly shown on PUC analysis report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm5mO.png)

[Data in previsualizing mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psgnU.png)

[Data in dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU34Z.png)

I expect that a numbers like 2865 is shown, instead of `null2865` in previsualizing mode and `NaN` when finished editing. In the end it seems that Pentaho correctly processes the numbers and makes operations like ordering based on them, but it doesn't display said numbers at all. I have no problem working with that data when doing any other task, like creating an Analysis Report, do you know what's happening here?

Comment: Does the query give the expected results when you run it from a SQL client? It looks like there was some attempt to sum numbers with + but it ended up concatenating them as strings because of the "null" in the first field. In general, start with the source table and trace the field, see where it turns from number to string data.

Comment: @Cyrus I ran the query and the results are what I expected. Also, the numbers shown when previsualizing are correct as far as I can tell, and they are the same numbers that Pentaho gets when I create a Analysis Report, for example. It's just that Pentaho appends a 'null' in front of them for some reason

Comment: Do you mean previewing when editing the (cda) data source or previewing the dashboard in the dashboard editor?

Comment: @Cyrus Previewing the table in the dashboard editor

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the Table component settings? It's likely there is some column format, number format or other setting that tries to add an invalid/empty value.

Comment: @Cyrus I've just added them

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Table Component is applying incorrect formatting to the column.

Check the "Column Formats" property first, there might be a missing comma there.

If that setting is empty, there might be a mistake in Column Types or in one of the extra functions if you have defined any.

[image]

Comment: How can I get to that screen?

Comment: Hmmm... What are you using exactly to edit that table? I kind of assumed you were using the Community Dashboard Editor

Comment: I'm creating a dashboard in the Pentaho User Console

Comment: Enterprise Edition

Comment: Ah, then this doesn't apply. I have no experience with the dashboards in the EE, so can't help you there. Have you tried the official Pentaho support?

Comment: Not yet, I guess I will now. Thanks for your help